# requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)

Tags: android

Plz someone give me the unity of *minDistance* on this method 
requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)

thanks in advance

Comment: unit for it is : meters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

> minDistance   float: minimum distance between location updates, in **meters**

Answer (score 0):

From API:

minDistance     float: minimum distance between location updates, **in meters**